# Confusion on inversion of control in React

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and came across something called "Inversion of control". Then, after some research done here https://dev.to/loweisz/use-the-inversion-of-control-pattern-with-react-4k72 I still find the term a bit confusing, that is, is it true that all inversion of control means is that instead of adding more than two props into a component, it is best to create additional custom component that handles that one additional props logic? DOes inversion of control kinda recommends to not put a lot of props into single component in order not to complicate that component. Is that true? I just need your kind clarification

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get familiar with **Inversion of Control**. It is a general concept related to almost all modern programing languages/paradigms. It's not a 'React' thing.

Inversion of control is a pattern or a concept in software design, specially (but not exclusive) Object Oriented software, that helps to keep, among other things, it loosely coupled.

One of the methods of achieving it is through **Dependency Injection**.

This small example of a pseudo code getting data from a database and displaying it:

```
class SomeScreenRenderer {

   constructor() {
       this.dbQuery = new MyDatabaseClass();
   }
   
   const showDataOnScreen = () => {
       Screen.show(this.dbQuery.getMyData());
   }
   
}
```

Versus:

```
class SomeScreenRendererWithDependencyInjection {

   constructor(dbHandlerInjected) {
       this.dbQuery = dbHandlerInjected
   }
   
   const showDataOnScreen = () => {
       Screen.show(this.dbQuery.getMyData());
   }
   
}
```

In simple terms, the later class uses Dependency Injection pattern to get a instance of some database handler it needs, but, instead of creating it, and therefore getting coupled with a specific implementation, the instance gets **injected** into it. This pattern makes possible to our system to change databases freely without having to change the client class.

You can learn more in the great [Martin Fowler Article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl)

Now, in the react components, props, etc, you can apply these concepts in order to make components independent and exchangeable.

The [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) technique for example, allows you to create a component that gets the data and render it using another component that it knows nothing about, the renderer gets injected into it.